# IdTCPClient cannot connect through weak internet connections

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I have a simple procedure that uses TIdTCPClient to connect to a server. Its purpose is to try to reach the server and block the thread until the connection is established. It works well with stable internet connections. The problem is, when this client is executed on some computers (all of these computers have slow or unstable internet connection like mobile 3G or just in small distant towns), it always fails to connect with "Connect timed out" exception. At the same time abovementioned computers run browsers, IM clients, etc, and these applications work fine. My server application also shows no sign of new client.

Here is the procedure:

```
procedure ConnectToServer;
begin
  EnterCriticalSection(CS_Connect);
  try
    while not Client.Connected do
    begin
      Log('Connection attempt...');
      Client.Port := <port goes here>;
      Client.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
      Client.Host := '<ip address here>';
      Client.ConnectTimeout := 11500;

      try
        Client.Connect;
      except
        on E: Exception do
          Log('Exception: ' + E.ToString);
      end;

      if Client.Connected then
      begin
        Log('Connected after ' + inttostr(attempts) + ' failed attempts');
        Client.IOHandler.WriteLn(MSG_HELLO);
        attempts := 0;
        exit;
      end;
      Inc(attempts);
      Log('Connection attempt failed');
      Sleep( min(attempts * 1000, 50000) );
    end;
  finally
    LeaveCriticalSection(CS_Connect);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Wrapping this code with EnterCriticalSection/LeaveCriticalSection looks like more than one thread could attempt to execute the ConnectToServer method, using the same ('global') TIdTCPClient. So thread A connects, leaves the section, and thread B would try to connect an already opened connection "again" - the critical section does not prevent this.

Comment: Critical section is just a precaution here, at least for now. The procedure is executed once from the main thread and also in timer thread (CreateTimerQueueTimer()) when it finds out that the connection is lost.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong (though your use of `Connected` is redundant).  Indy uses the same socket API that other apps use. They all use the same underlying `connect()` function.  So the problem is not with Indy, it is with the OS itself.  Since you have a weak signal, it is hit/miss when any given connection will succeed or fail.

Comment: It seems wierd to me though that my application is the only one that is never able to connect even for a moment.